# Debugging .net using SOS

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg, sos

I have created a dump using clrdump.  When I go to view it using sos, I load up sos and then run !dso, but the error I get is:

```
PDB symbol for mscorwks.dll not loaded
```

However, in the module window it says that the symbol is loaded.  I have obtained the up to date symbols from the MS store?

Anybody any ideas?

Thanks,

Darren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need symbols for `mscorwks.dll` for `!dso` to work correctly, but here's some advice on how to get the symbols.

First thing you need to do is to verify that you did set the symbol path? You can view the current setting for the symbol path using the `.sympath` command. You can either download all the symbols and point the symbol path to the location on the disc, or just use the online symbol server. In either case the symbol path must point to the correct location.

You can use the `.symfix` command to point to Microsoft's public symbol server, which is probably the easiest way to get symbols (provided you have online access).

Use the `lm` command to see modules and their symbols. If it says `pdb symbols` next to a module everything is okay. Keep in mind that WinDbg will only load symbols as needed, so for a lot of modules you will probably see `deferred`. You can force loading symbols for all modules using the `.reload /f` command.

To troubleshoot loading of symbols use the `!sym noisy` command. It will tell you where the debugger is trying to locate the PDB files.

Comment: Hi,  the sym noisy command does not work for me.  It says error: missing operand?  Any ideas?

Comment: @Darren: Did you include the `!`? The command is `!sym` and the argument is `noisy`.

Comment: I did.  I have since tried this using Windbg rather than VS debugger and it works fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
!sym noisy    
.symfix
.reload -f
```