# Application crash on start without exception raised

Tags: debugging, windbg

I am trying to track what causes my application to **crash on start** when launched from production. When launched from debug in Visual Studio, this C#/.NET windows application starts without any problem, and results are as expected. Previous versions of the same application have also been deployed and ran on other client computers.
Reading from the explanation found in [Windows Error Reporting and CLR integration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/01/30/windows-error-reporting-wer-and-clr-integration.aspx), it seems my problems comes from a method in assembly ExcelInterop.

```
Error Bucket , type 0      
Event Name : CLR20r3
Answer : Non available
CAB ID : 0

Problem signature : 
P1 : afiv2.exe          ' my application
P2 : 0.19.4826.21736
P3 : 51489aa0
P4 : ExcelInterop       ' my library
P5 : 1.0.0.0
P6 : 514878d9
P7 : 13             ' MethodDescr ???
P8 : 56
P9 : PSZQOADHX1U5ZAHBHOHGHLDGIY4QIXHX
P10 :
```

Trying to locate the error I launched the application using windbg.exe menu-->File-->Open Executable (first time I use windbg), but console showed that Symbol search path was invalid. 
As per [Debugging .net using SOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244670/debugging-net-using-sos), I recovered symbol path using the following command sequence:

```
!sym noisy    
.symfix
.reload -f
```

First trial loading SOS lead to an "Unable to find module mscorwks" error, [Help:Failed to load sos in windbg](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/e609dc9b-bf6f-4f49-9f51-5c3a4a5efa2d/) solved this part of the problem:

```
sxe ld:mscorlib
g
.loadby sos mscorwks
!token2ee ExcelInterop 06000013
```

I expected that the last command would determine the methodDesc associated with the number in the event report, but nothing was returned.

I now feel trapped in a kind of maze. What else should be done to find what is causing the crash on start?

---

Details of the windbg session

```
<pre>
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.11.0001.404 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: C:\Users\spel\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\49619QZC.EY2\B8TZ2OKL.D49\afiv..tion_0000000000000000_0000.0016_22cd035f134c19e0\AFIv2.exe
Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***
****************************************************************************
* Symbol loading may be unreliable without a symbol search path.           *
* Use .symfix to have the debugger choose a symbol path.                   *
* After setting your symbol path, use .reload to refresh symbol locations. *
****************************************************************************
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00000000`00290000 00000000`0048e000   AFIv2.exe
ModLoad: 00000000`76f00000 00000000`770a9000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f89e0000 000007fe`f8a4f000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`76820000 00000000`7693f000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fd450000 000007fe`fd4bb000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
(121c.1494): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
ntdll!CsrSetPriorityClass+0x40:
00000000`76facb60 cc              int     3
0:000> .path
           ^ Syntax error in '.path'
0:000> .winpath
              ^ Syntax error in '.winpath'
0:000> .sympath
Symbol search path is: <empty>
Expanded Symbol search path is: <empty>
0:000> !sym noisy
noisy mode - symbol prompts on
0:000> .symfix
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: cache*C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
0:000> .reload -f
Reloading current modules
.
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\AFIv2.pdb\7C97CCD8E9CD4E26B6039C225A56890B15\AFIv2.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\AFIv2.pdb\7C97CCD8E9CD4E26B6039C225A56890B15\AFIv2.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/AFIv2.pdb/7C97CCD8E9CD4E26B6039C225A56890B15/AFIv2.pdb not found
DBGHELP: C:\Users\spel\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\49619QZC.EY2\B8TZ2OKL.D49\afiv..tion_0000000000000000_0000.0016_22cd035f134c19e0\AFIv2.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\Users\spel\Documents\GCRH complet\trunk\AFI_CS\IHM\obj\Debug\AFIv2.pdb cached to C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\AFIv2.pdb\7C97CCD8E9CD4E26B6039C225A56890B15\AFIv2.pdb
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for AFIv2.exe
DBGHELP: AFIv2 - private symbols & lines 
         C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\AFIv2.pdb\7C97CCD8E9CD4E26B6039C225A56890B15\AFIv2.pdb
.
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\kernel32.pdb\C4312728BA1F4691955E99B2E026FAFC2\kernel32.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  kernel32.pdb from http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 668117 bytes - copied         
DBGHELP: C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\kernel32.pdb\C4312728BA1F4691955E99B2E026FAFC2\kernel32.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: KERNEL32 - public symbols  
         C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\kernel32.pdb\C4312728BA1F4691955E99B2E026FAFC2\kernel32.pdb
.
DBGHELP: ntdll - public symbols  
         C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\15EB43E23B12409C84E3CC7635BAF5A32\ntdll.pdb
.
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\mscoree.pdb\FB53EF9DD104439E9903F0B34128E0392\mscoree.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  mscoree.pdb from http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 294166 bytes - copied         
DBGHELP: C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\mscoree.pdb\FB53EF9DD104439E9903F0B34128E0392\mscoree.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: MSCOREE - public symbols  
         C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\mscoree.pdb\FB53EF9DD104439E9903F0B34128E0392\mscoree.pdb
.
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\kernelbase.pdb\91C72371DD43448192B7B46F5ED10AA02\kernelbase.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  kernelbase.pdb from http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 231949 bytes - copied         
DBGHELP: C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\kernelbase.pdb\91C72371DD43448192B7B46F5ED10AA02\kernelbase.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: KERNELBASE - public symbols  
         C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\kernelbase.pdb\91C72371DD43448192B7B46F5ED10AA02\kernelbase.pdb

0:000> .loadby sos mscorwks
Unable to find module 'mscorwks'
0:000> sxe ld:mscorlib
0:000> g
ModLoad: 000007fe`f35e0000 000007fe`f44bc000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\mscorlib\51a23687fdafc32b697f5a719e364651\mscorlib.ni.dll
ntdll!ZwMapViewOfSection+0xa:
00000000`76f5159a c3              ret
0:000> .loadby sos mscorwks
0:000> !token2ee afi 06000013
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\mscorwks.pdb\E5BD5716E1D64C1C86661A5AAF7DD9251\mscorwks.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  mscorwks.pdb from http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 2000973 bytes - copied         
DBGHELP: C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\mscorwks.pdb\E5BD5716E1D64C1C86661A5AAF7DD9251\mscorwks.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: mscorwks - public symbols  
         C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\mscorwks.pdb\E5BD5716E1D64C1C86661A5AAF7DD9251\mscorwks.pdb
0:000> !token2ee ExcelInterop 06000013
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead set `sxe clr` which would break on first chance of the exception. And then doing a `!clrstack` would give call-stack.

The Methoddsec 06000013  could be different based on JIT so you could be looking at pointer that would not give you a result.

HTH

Comment: Thank you Naveen. This `sxe clr` to break on first chance of the exception did the work. I finally got the trace I needed to continue debugging.